# Accessing request object in django urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

The question is also inspired from documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf).

I am using generic view (**ListView**) in Django in order to list out all the questions, current logged in user has asked. I was curious to do it without creating a View in `views.py`. So in urls.py I added a path like:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('myqn/', login_required(views.ListView.as_view(model=models.Question, queryset=models.Question.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id), template_name='testapp/question_list.html', context_object_name='questions')), name='myqn'),
]
```

Its giving me that:

> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

I know it. Since, request object is passed by the URLConf to the View class/function. So, is there a way, I can access the user.id in this scope.

PS: The code works if I replace `user__id=9`. It lists out all the questions asked by user-9. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can't.
The **`as_view()`** accepts ***any class attributes*** of a view class. In your case, the **`request`** object will not accessible from the class

```
class Foo(ListView):
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
```

The above snippet you can't reference the `request` and hence also in your `urls.py`

In these kinds of *complex* situations, we should override the `get_queryset()`, as you know.

Answer (score 6):

You normally do this by *overriding* the `get_queryset` method in a *subclass* of the `ListView`. So you can create a view:

```
# app/views.py

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from app.models import Question

class QuestionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name='testapp/question_list.html'
    context_object_name='questions'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            user_id=self.request.user.id
        )
```

In the `urls.py` you then use the `QuestionListView`

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import QuestionListView

urlpatterns += [
    path('myqn/', QuestionListView.as_view(), name='myqn'),
]
```

You can define a function or lambda expression with:

```
import inspect

def custom_queryset(*args, **kwargs):
    self = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals['self']
    return Question.objects.filter(
        user_id=self.request.user.id
    )

urlpatterns += [
    path('myqn/', QuestionListView.as_view(get_queryset=custom_queryset), name='myqn'),
]
```

This is however not a good idea. First of all, it inspects the call stack, and if later the `ListView` is altered, it might not work anymore. Furthermore here this listview will not check if the user has logged in for example. We can not make use of the *method resolution order (MRO)* to make a call to a `super()` method.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I could do it this way. But I wanted to know If I could complete it without creating Class in views.py

Comment: @Pax: I don't see why creating a new class is such a problem?

Comment: Both of them works pretty same. But, in order to minimize code in views.py, I am learning a way to write in in my urls.py. So maybe later if i create queryset filter with suppose date and other, I might not need to populate my views.py.
In simple: Just for fast development :)

Comment: @Pax: but you can still add extra attributes in the `.as_view` of the `QuestionListView`, so if you really want this, you can make some `OwnerListView` that filters on the `user_id`, and then thus use `OwnerListView.as_view(model=Question)` for example. Normally it is not a good idea to put so much details. In fact it is seldomly done for `ListView`s, etc. You probably can work with a lambda-expression, but that would be both very chaotic, and furthermore "unstable" in the sense that you can not make use of the MRO for `super()` resolution.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you can, please add a sample of lambda with these unstable detail. so I can accept this answer as the solution

Comment: I think time spent on this q&a outweighs the savings on creating classes in views.py for a number of years.

Comment: @Melvyn: well a subclass is imho better since it is more *clean*. It also is quite easy to override, or to mix in mixins for example (like the `LoginRequiredMixin`). The idea of using something like `ListView.as_view(model=...)` is if it is really a simple case that does not need anything else. From the moment more complicated behavior is necessary, I would advise to use subclasses. The approach in the answer more demonstrates that this strictly speaking *can* be done, but is not very elegant, and is rather "unstable".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I'm allergic to kluding urls.py with view logic, so we're in agreement. I don't think it's where development time will be saved as OP suggests. I do think that the person inheriting a collection of lambda's in urls.py will be [fairly annoyed](https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/).